# How to apply a gradient to an (fixed width) image that is responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, linear-gradients

I'm not sure how to explain my question. So here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8zsqydj0/

```css
.background-img-wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

.background-img-wrapper {
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.background:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row justify-content-center position-fixed background">
  <div class="background-img-wrapper">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/000000/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply a gradient to three sides of the image. That far I got. However, the image is centered on the page and has a fixed (max) width of 1920px. The gradient is applied to a parent div that is 100% of the page and the image is img-fluid. So, when the gradient is viewed on a resolution of 1920px or lower everything looks fine. However, when you resize the page **above** a width of 1920px, the gradient moves with the side of the window instead of staying fixed at the sides of the image. If that makes sense.

So, how to apply the gradient to the image instead of the parent div, or how to limit the sides of the gradient to the image size? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Also, I don't necessarily need to keep the current structure. If there's a better way to achieve all this please do let me know :)

Comment: position:relative to `.background-img-wrapper`?

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion! That does work in regards to limiting the left/right gradient to the sides of the images. But it (re?)moves my bottom gradient.

Comment: `z-index: 1;` to the other gradient

Comment: Wow, that worked! Many thanks! If you post it as full answer, I can mark it as a solution if you want. Side question if you feel like it: any idea if it is possible to get rid of the background-img-wrapper entirely? I feel like it's kinda useless. Anyway, my main problem is fixed. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I will replace `1920px` with a smaller value so we can better see the result</sup>

An easy fix would be to add `position:relative` and adjust `z-index` like below:

```css
.background-img-wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

.background-img-wrapper {
    max-width: 400px;
    position:relative; /* added */
}

.background:before {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1; /* added */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="row justify-content-center position-fixed background">
  <div class="background-img-wrapper">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/000000/"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simplify your code like below:

```css
.background:before {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: 
     linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 80%, #fff 100%),
     linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, transparent 20%  80%, #fff 100%);
}

.background {
    max-width: 400px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="position-fixed background m-auto">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/000000/"/>
</div>
```

If the ratio of the image will always be the same you can still simplify:

```css
.background:before {
    content: "";
    padding-top:calc(300/400 * 100%); /* Height/width */
}

.background {
    max-width: 400px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: 
     linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 80%, #fff 100%),
     linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, transparent 20%  80%, #fff 100%),
     url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/000000/) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="position-fixed background m-auto d-flex">
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm and looks much simpler. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: @Landcross added another simplification ;)